# How to make VS2017 match configuration and platform selection when I open Setup Property Pages for a C++ or MFC project?

Tags: c++, configuration, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I'm migrating my C++ and MFC projects to Visual Studio 2017 and this little change that they had made to it caused me a lot of confusion.

Say, if I'm currently working in a `Debug` `x86` configuration for my project, when I go to the `Property Page` for my project, instead of matching the selection for my current configuration, it shows something that, I guess, it remembered since last time I opened it. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I would expect the property page window to be selected for `Debug x86` as well to match my current configuration, instead of being set to `Release x64`.

Is there a way to configure it to match when I open the `Property Page` settings?

Comment: Sounds to me like a question for the MS VC team. Not SO.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Well, I'm hoping that there's a setting that I missed somewhere.

Comment: why does that make it more of a SO than a MSVC team question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the active platform in your property page then they should match:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I guess they want us to select "Active" to make it match what's actually selected in the IDE. Well, that's not exactly what I was looking for but will do for a downfall that VS has become now.

Comment: That raises the question - what is better than Visual Studio?. I find VS very productive and now use it for Linux dev as well.

Comment: Older versions of VS that don't crash, are fast to load, don't have tons of bloat, and don't take GBs of data to download for an update.

Comment: @c00000fd You only have to select "Active" once. From then on, the project properties dialog always follows your current configuration. Even when closing/reopening a project.